# Is there a D7 module that allows you to create a content type to be displayed as a system message?

Tags: 7

Is there a D7 module that allows you to create a content type to displayed as a system message?

Something like http://drupal.org/project/user_alert but gets displayed in the system messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a lot of overhead for this one function but [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) can trigger arbitrary system messages with Token support. Here is a [screencast by Node One](http://nodeone.se/blogg/learn-rules-with-nodeone-part-1-overview) which can give you an overview and he does the system message example in a couple of the videos. I think that if you need extended interaction with users Rules can be very helpful.

Comment: I considered this. However, is there a way to keep the message shown to all users until the node is deleted?

Comment: I'm not sure what your particular case is. However, in the video, Johan Falk shows a case of using the Flag module Rule integration. A rule can be created where if a flag on the node is set, the rule will trigger a system message to be shown until the flag is either unset or the node is deleted or another condition is met such as the node is unpublished.